# Qué significa la certificación de seguridad en un administrador de base de datos?

Tags: mariadb

Tengo el siguiente link:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_relational_database_management_systems#Access_control

Y estoy interesado en saber más sobre MariaDB y en la sección de "Access control" dice que ese administrador no tiene certificación de seguridad, pero quisiera saber un poco más a profundidad qué es eso.

Psdta.:
Si su respuesta se puede respaldar con fuentes bibliográficas, mucho mejor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta no es una pregunta sobre software y creo que pedir un respaldo bibliográfico está un tanto fuera de lugar. Pero como es un tema oscuro creo que vale la pena arrojar un poco de luz al respecto:

La certificación de tipo EAL con que cuentan algunos paquetes de Software es en la práctica **un negocio**.

Le tienes que pagar una fortuna a una empresa externa que llega, mira tu software y lo aprueba o rechaza en base a ciertos criterios. Posiblemente ni siquiera entienden lo que están evaluando sino que le aplican un análisis parametrizado.

Lo más cercano a una fuente que pude encontrar en los foros de MariaDB es esto:

> Obtaining EAL certification involves spending hundreds of thousands of
>   dollars (even millions for the top levels) to have the software
>   externally evaluated. It makes no practical difference, except that
>   certain customers (such as, I believe, some US government entities)
>   may insist on it.

Respaldo Bibliográfico: [According to wikipedia link, MariaDB does not have Security Evaluation Assurance Level (EAL)](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-community-according-to-wikipedia-link-mariadb-does-not-have-securit/)

Comment: entonces no es estrictamente necesario?

Comment: Es un cartón arbitrario como lo son muchas certificaciones. Casi todo lo que no es un estándar ISO o SAE son certificaciones arbitrarias

Comment: entiendo gracias por la respuesta